# Linker errors with google unit test framework

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2008, linker, googletest

I created a test console exe project to test my program in VS2008!

Linked gtestd.lib to that project with following code

**MAIN**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

return this linker errors:

```
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ___report_rangecheckfailure referenced in function "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl testing::internal::CodePointToUtf8(unsigned int)" (?CodePointToUtf8@internal@testing@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@I@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> >::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> >(void)" (??0?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::_Container_base12::~_Container_base12(void)" (__imp_??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "public: __thiscall std::_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> >::~_String_val<struct std::_Simple_types<char> >(void)" (??1?$_String_val@U?$_Simple_types@D@std@@@std@@QAE@XZ)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: struct std::_Iterator_base12 * * __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Getpfirst(void)const " (__imp_?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ) referenced in function "protected: void __thiscall std::_Tree<class std::_Tset_traits<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,0> >::_Orphan_ptr(class std::_Tree<class std::_Tset_traits<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,0> > &,struct std::_Tree_node<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void *> *)const " (?_Orphan_ptr@?$_Tree@V?$_Tset_traits@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@IBEXAAV12@PAU?$_Tree_node@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAX@2@@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Orphan_all(void)" (__imp_?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function __catch$??$_Insert@PBQBD@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@QAEXV?$_Vector_const_iterator@V?$_Vector_val@U?$_Simple_types@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@std@@@1@PBQBD1Uforward_iterator_tag@1@@Z$0
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall std::_Container_base12::_Swap_all(struct std::_Container_base12 &)" (__imp_?_Swap_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXAAU12@@Z) referenced in function "?_Assign_rv@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@QAEX$$QAV12@@Z" (?_Assign_rv@?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@QAEX$$QAV12@@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xbad_alloc(void)" (__imp_?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "char * __cdecl std::_Allocate<char>(unsigned int,char *)" (??$_Allocate@D@std@@YAPADIPAD@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xlength_error(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "protected: class std::_Tree_const_iterator<class std::_Tree_val<struct std::_Tree_simple_types<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > > __thiscall std::_Tree<class std::_Tset_traits<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::less<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,0> >::_Insert_at<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct std::_Nil>(bool,struct std::_Tree_node<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,void *> *,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,struct std::_Nil)" (??$_Insert_at@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U_Nil@2@@?$_Tree@V?$_Tset_traits@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$less@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@$0A@@std@@@std@@IAE?AV?$_Tree_const_iterator@V?$_Tree_val@U?$_Tree_simple_types@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@std@@@std@@@1@_NPAU?$_Tree_node@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@PAX@1@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@1@U_Nil@1@@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) void __cdecl std::_Xout_of_range(char const *)" (__imp_?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >::_Xran(void)const " (?_Xran@?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QBEXXZ)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Syserror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class std::error_condition __thiscall std::_System_error_category::default_error_condition(int)const " (?default_error_condition@_System_error_category@std@@UBE?AVerror_condition@2@H@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) char const * __cdecl std::_Winerror_map(int)" (__imp_?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall std::_System_error_category::message(int)const " (?message@_System_error_category@std@@UBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@2@H@Z)
1>gtestd.lib(gtest-all.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __int64 __thiscall std::ios_base::width(void)const " (__imp_?width@ios_base@std@@QBE_JXZ) referenced in function "class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __cdecl std::operator<<<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??$?6DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@1@@std@@YAAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AAV10@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@0@@Z)
```

Notes:

- compiled all projects with MD or MD(d)
- at the moment no tests defined (only main)

Anything still wrong here? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution for VS2012:

1. use the **gtest-md** solution file if your other projects are compiled with **/md**
2. set `_VARIADIC_MAX=10` as preprocessor definition
3. maybe you have to change the compiler to VS2008 if your project-to-test also use this compiler

Greets